# Run task only if invoked from command line with dependency on another task even if it fails

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'll explain my use case first and then the generalized description of what I want to do.

## Use case: Open test results

The default `$gradle test` will run the `test` task and run all unit tests. I would like to add a `browseTest` task which will, if specified on the command line, open the test report in the default browser. I already have the code to open the test result, but I need to figure out how to execute it. Here is how I think it should work:

| Command | Tests up-to-date | Run tests? | Test result? | Open test report? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | no | yes | success/failure | no |
| test | yes | no | success/failure | no |
| browseTest | no | yes | success/failure | yes |
| browseTest | yes | no | success/failure | yes |

## General case

I want to be able to have one task (i.e. `browseTest`) add another task (e.g. `task`) to the task graph without depending on the other task succeeding or failing. If I use `dependsOn` then the first take failing prevents the second task from executing. Using `mustRunAfter` specifies an ordering but doesn't add the task to the task graph (and thus will not be executed).

If there was something akin to the following, I believe it would get me what I want:

```kotlin
task("browseTest") {
    addsToTaskGraph("test")
    mustRunAfter("test")
    doLast {
        // Open test results in browser
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answer

I answered my own question again. I was able to successfully create a `runsAfter` extension function. I would love to be able to clean up the logic for triggering the callback/hook, but overall this is very user-friendly and not overly ineffecient.

```kotlin
val browseTest = task("browseTest") {
    runsAfter(tasks.test.name) {
        // perform "callback"
        val file = project.file("build/reports/tests/test/index.html")
        browse(file.absolutePath)
    }
}

fun Task.runsAfter(vararg paths: String, action: () -> Unit) {
    val parent = this
    val helper = task("${name}__runsAfter") {
        doLast {
            if (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(parent)) {
                action()
            }
        }
    }
    paths.forEach {
        dependsOn(it)
        tasks[it].finalizedBy(helper)
    }
}
```

---

## Original Answer

I was able to get this working, although I don't really like the result. If anyone has any other ideas, please let me know.

```kotlin
val browseTest = task("browseTest") {
    dependsOn("test")
    val parent = this
    val helper = task("browseTestHelper") {
        doLast {
            if (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(parent)) {
                // Open test results in browser
                val file = project.file("build/reports/tests/test/index.html")
                browse(file.absolutePath)
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.test {
        finalizedBy(helper)
    }
}
```

There are a few pieces here:

1. The `browseTest` task depends on `test`, which means that it will force `test` to run if it is specified.
2. The `browseTest` task doesn't actually *do* anything.
3. A `browseTestHelper` task is created.
4. The `test` task is configured to be "finalized" by the `browseTestHelper`.
5. When the `browseTestHelper` runs, it checks to see if the original `browseTest` task is in the task graph. If not, it doesn't do anything.

   - This is necessary because the `browseTestHelper` task is created and finalizes `test` even if the `browseTest` task is not invoked.
6. If `browseTest` is in the task graph, it performs its actions.

There are a few ways this could improve:

1. Is there a better way to access the "parent" task other than the `val parent = this` line?
2. Can you conditionally add finalizers to a task while also seeing if a task is present in the task graph?

   - I'm guessing not, since the act of adding a finalizer affects the task graph.
3. Is there a way to wrap this all in a function that you could invoke with just a function call?

It would be great to do something like this:

```kotlin
val browseTest = task("browseTest") {
    runsAfter("test") {
        val file = project.file("build/reports/tests/test/index.html")
        browse(file.absolutePath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer seems to be way to complicated. It seems to me that the essence of your question is to not let the task `test` fail when `browseTest` will be part of the build:

> If I use `dependsOn` then the first task failing prevents the second task from executing.

Well, you can simply prevent the task `test` from failing the build by using its `ignoreFailures` property. Combine this property with your condition and you are good to go.

I'll use Groovy code here, because I'm not that familiar with the Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
test {
    doFirst {
        ignoreFailures = gradle.taskGraph.hasTask('browseTest')
    }
}

task browseTest {
    dependsOn 'test'
    doLast {
        // open in browser
    }
}
```

Comment: I really, really don't want to prevent tasks from failing. If there are other tasks that are only performed on a successful test then I _wouldn't_ want to do them if the test failed, even if I happened to be opening a test report. I _really_ want the ability to depend on a test that may or may not fail, but it doesn't look like Gradle supports. This is definitely shorter and sweeter as a quick fix though :)